# Ionic 2: Choose the .apk to run

Tags: ionic-framework, apk, ionic2, crosswalk

I've installed the crosswalk plugin and built my app with `cordova build --release`.
This generated 2 apk files: `android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk` and `android-x86-release-unsigned.apk`. Now I would like to run my app on my device using one of these apk's, but when I run `ionic run android --device`, it builds 2 more apks and uses `android-armv7-debug.apk` to run the app.
How can I choose the apk that my app needs to use ?

Thanks

Edit: here's `config.xml`

[image]

Comment: you can just run cordova run android and it will build the apk, install on the devide and run it(should connect the device via usb :P)

Answer (score 1):

You should be running with `release` and `prod` flags.

```
ionic run android --prod --release
```

Check the [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/deploying/)
By default it will build and run debug apks.

Comment: I figured in the end that the only thing I want to do is run my app and make sure that it is running on Crosswalk, so I don't need to use a release version of the apk, do I ? It is said on the [Crosswalk website](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html) that when the app is running, you can check that it uses Crosswalk by inspecting `navigator.userAgent`, but it doesn't appear in my console... Any idea ?

Comment: You seem to be mixing both cordova and ionic commands.. I mentioned the flags as per the question of choosing the build or release apk. For crosswalk, you can use `ionic run android` directly, it will call the corresponding cordova command.

Comment: did you install crosswalk through ionic-native?

Comment: I installed it with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`. And no matter what apk is used to run the app, it's not running with crosswalk.

Comment: do you have an entry in config.xml for crosswalk? if not uninstall and reinstall with `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

Comment: I didn't, uninstalled and reinstalled with ionic, still no entry in config.xml...

Comment: can you share config.xml?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Comment: which os version are you trying for?

Comment: Android version ? 5.0.1

Comment: ?? ionic should work without crosswalk.. Crosswalk is needed if your version is 4.4 to around 4.2(not sureof lowest one)

Comment: Well I am currently testing on my device but the goal of the app is to work on devices running on older versions so I should be able to try it on mine first shouldn't I ?

Comment: ok try `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --save` installing with save and check config.xml again

Comment: It added `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="~2.2.0" />` to config.xml! But I still can't make sure that the app is running with crosswalk as they explain it on their website.

Comment: try in an emulator with android version lower than 4.4

Comment: ionic by itself does not support lower than 4.4

Comment: Ok I will try that and come back here, thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi, I've tryed with an emulator running on 4.3 but still not running with crosswalk...